# add multiple geoJSON sources with mapbox GL Js

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to add another source with a new layer to the map with the type geoJSON on the map (mapbox).

I am getting the error message

> ERROR Error: There is already a source with this ID

How can I add another geo-source in typescript with a new map.addSource besides an existing geo-source?

First geo-source:

```
          map.addSource("polygon", create(coordinates, 0.5, 64));
          map.addLayer({
            "id": "polygon",
            "type": "fill",
            "source": "polygon",
            "layout": {},
            "paint": {
              'fill-color': {
                type: 'identity',
                property: 'color',
              },
              'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 1)',
              "fill-opacity": 0.090
            }
          });
```

in method:

```
    return {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [ret]
          }
        }]
      }
    };
```

second source:

```
          map.addSource('places', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': activitiesPlaces
          });

       var activitiesPlaces = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {
              'name': valuesName
            },
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates':
                valuesLon,
              valuesLat
            }
          }
        ]
      };
```

calling this source gives me the error message

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the [`Map#addSource`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addsource) method specifies a source ID for the particular source. Each source ID in a map style must be unique, as noted in the API reference [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addsource):

> **Parameters**
>
> **`id`** (string) The ID of the source to add. Must not conflict with existing sources.

So, specifying unique source IDs for each source added to the map will resolve the error.

Comment: The code from the original poster has distinct ids: 'polygon' and 'places'. I have the same issue, and the ids for each source are distinct (they come from an array I iterate over).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding multiple sources, you should try adding multiple layers.

```js
    map.addLayer({
            id: 'features-fill',
            type: 'fill',
            source: 'features',
            paint: {'fill-color': 'red', 'fill-opacity': 0.6}
        });

    map.addLayer({
            id: 'features-fill-1',
            type: 'fill',
            source: 'features',
            paint: {'fill-color': 'blue', 'fill-opacity': 0.8}
        });
```

> UPDATE:

```
map.once('load', function loaded() {
    map.batch(function batch() {
        features.forEach(function eachFilter(feature, index) {
            var id = 'feature-' + index;
            map.addSource(id, {type: 'geojson', data: feature});
            map.addLayer({
                id: id + '-fill',
                type: 'fill',
                source: id,
                paint: {'fill-color': 'red', 'fill-opacity': 0.6}
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Check out this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1484

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Its not about adding another layer of that same type. Its a geo layer with a different source structure.

Comment: With your example, I'm always getting this error: TypeError: map.batch is not a function... can u help me?